# Can user add new Sections in a view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am using eclipse 3.6 and developing RCP application with java 6.
I am using the Section and trying to let the use able to add new n-sections. I need the text in the field after that.

Now the User can see a section. I need that he is able to add a n-sections and then to write text in stopRouteStreet-field. I would like to read all the n Text written in this field.

Any idea how to do this?.

Here is my code

```
Section sectionStop = toolkit.createSection(form.getBody(), Section.DESCRIPTION|Section.TWISTIE|Section.TITLE_BAR);         
td = new TableWrapData(TableWrapData.FILL);
td.colspan = 2;
sectionStop.setLayoutData(td);
sectionStop.addExpansionListener(new ExpansionAdapter() {
    public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
        form.reflow(true);
    }
});

sectionStop.setText(Messages.SearchMapView_endPoint); //$NON-NLS-1$

Composite sectionClientStop = toolkit.createComposite(sectionStop);
sectionClientStop.setLayout(new GridLayout());

final Composite stopComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sectionClientStop, SWT.NONE);
final GridLayout gridLayoutStop = new GridLayout();
gridLayoutStop.numColumns = 2;
stopComposite.setLayout(gridLayoutStop);
toolkit.createLabel(stopComposite, Messages.SearchMapView_Street);
stopRouteStreet = toolkit.createText(stopComposite, "", SWT.BORDER); //$NON-NLS-1$
sectionStop.setClient(sectionClientStop);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a global variable (a HashMap would do), that saves a mapping between each newly created Section and the Text control.

```
// define global field

HashMap <Section, Text> dynamicControls = new HashMap <Section, Text> ();   

// after you create the text field, save the newly created Text field
....
...

dynamicControls.put(section, text);

// Later when you need to read the values in all the text fields 
for(Section s: dynamicControls.keySet()){
        Text textField = dynamicControls.get(s); 
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
}
```